# getConfig from extension to lib file, how?

Tags: module, configuration

I want to use value of config.xml and system.xml file from module in a file when located in "lib" directory in root of magento, but I don't know how!

Tried many searches but didn't find my answer, because all of them use in classes and models of self extension, I need read from app/community/Company/Mymodule/etc/config.xml ...

Answer (score 1):

The whole configuration is merged into one big XML structure, therefore you can just access it via:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('globals/model/...');
```

But I'm not sure what happens with the system.xml

Have a look here, this should do.

```
\Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config::_initSectionsAndTabs

    $config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')
        ->applyExtends();

    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_init_system_config', array('config' => $config));
    $this->_sections = $config->getNode('sections');
    $this->_tabs = $config->getNode('tabs');
```

Comment: enough if I can use config.xml ...

Comment: any solution for reading from config.xml?
Not working "getNode...."

Comment: You are in Magento context, are you?

Comment: I have a file in "lib" directory and want to read and use a config value from an extension in community/Mycompnay/Mymodule/etc/config.xml(or system.xml) folder... yes I am!

Comment: can you please add your config.xml or at least the important part of it and the getNode call you made? And please edit your answer, to format it!

Comment: problem solved, I moved my file from "lib" folder to "extension" folder!